# Chrome breaks keyboard after software update

Tags: linux, google-chrome, keyboard

I run ElementaryOS Freya and this morning I installed some automatic updates (list of them below). None of the updates seem specifically related to Chrome. After restarting, whenever I have Chrome open, the keyboard doesn't work. No program will read input from it. As soon as I close Chrome, it works fine. I tried the obvious things, like restarting and reinstalling Chrome. Any suggestions?

[image]

edit: I fixed it. Not sure why, but resetting my keyboard configuration from terminal with 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration' worked, in case anyone else runs into this.

Comment: Did you try killing Chrome completely and starting a brand new browsing session?

Comment: I did a purge of it to uninstall. Should I be doing something more?

Comment: Since the updates you did are very unlikely relevant to your issue, I think the problem is either with Chrome's installation or a page that you open with it.  Try to make sure you do not reopen the same pages as you already have opened with it to make sure that's not the issue.  If it's not, then after making sure you have the latest Chrome release installed, file a bug report with them since a kernel change **should not** affect the keyboard for a single application.

Comment: Already filed. I've tried starting the session as incognito, and the default homepage is just google.